# Algorithm to compute a grid-layout given container size and items fixed aspect ratio

Tags: layout, geometry, grid

I'm looking for an algorithm to compute a grid layout. I will write it in javascript in the end but I'm looking for an agnostic-language answer.

I have a container (with a fixed dimension) and a variable number of elements.
All the elements have the same fixed aspect ratio and all the elements will have the same width/height, but it will change in proportion of the number of elements to fit the container.

As a plus I would like to know a margin between each elements to space them equally.

Ideally I immagine a function with this signature:

```
function computeLayout(containerWidth, containerHeight, numElements) {


   // ...

   return { itemWidth, itemHeight, margin }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let element width/height ratio is `C`. We need to put `n` rectangle elements  on the rectangular container with given `Width` and `Height`.

Let unknown element  height is `h`, width `w = C * h`

Every row of grid contains `nr` elements

```
nr =  Floor(Width / (C * h))   // rounding down
```

Every column contains `nc` rows

```
nc = Floor(Height / h)
```

So we can write inequality to provide place for `n` elements:

```
n <= nc * nr
n <=  Floor(Width / (C * h)) * Floor(Height / h)
```

and solve it for `h` (so find maximum possible `h` value)

Initial approximate value of `h`:

```
h0 = Ceil(Sqrt(Width * Height / (n * C)))   //rounding up
```

Then we can decrement `h` value until inequality becomes true like this:

```
while (n > Floor(Width / (C * h)) * Floor(Height / h))
   h--;
```

Margins introduce additional variability. We can predefine margin value and use it in `nc, nr` formulas (using `h + margin`, `C * h + margin`)

If you want to get minimal margin (perhaps zero) - just calculate it from difference of `Height` and `nr*h`

Comment: hei @Mbo thanks for your answer. It is quite clear thinking but it does not work for some cases, see this example with 5 elements: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-chaplygin-d2gd7

Comment: (happy to discuss in chat if you want!)

Comment: My mistake in stop-condition. Corrected to `while (   numElements >` (gives h=225 for 4 elements, h=200 for 5 elements). To avoid too much iterations for large values, one might use binary search.